# Export form with domain name association to new SharePoint site

Tags: 2010, 2016, form, export

I have a form on SharePoint 2010 that I would like to transfer over to SP2016. In 2010 we currently have over 300 forms filled out. They all have a domain name associated with them. How do I go about transferring the current forms (2010) to SP2016? I have exported them before, but the domain name association was lost in the transfer.

Comment: what's the type of forms?

Comment: @M.Qassas It is a list

Comment: is there InfoPath form ? or default form?

Comment: @M.Qassas A default form

Comment: Do you have any Metadata columns or lookups columns?

Comment: I did not implement Metadata columns or lookup columns. It is a list that contains multiple single line and multiple line texts boxes. With one column being type `Person or Group`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63467/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-kevorski).

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint generates a new ID for each user in each site collection and hence the user IDs are different  for the same user account across the site collection (across the different farms as well, even if the two farms uses the same Active Directory), as SharePoint creates the user profiles by importing information from Active Directory (by using the “User Profile Synchronization service”) and stored it locally in SharePoint once the synchronization is done.

For your case, you are trying to save the entire library (that contains forms) along with contents as template and re-use it in another farm and hence the users associated with the forms were not preserved, as SharePoint uses user’s ID as a metadata (as stated above, user IDs are different  for the same user account across the farms even if they uses the same domain). To preserve these users in the forms (across farms),either you have to write your own script to migrate each form, along with the user associated with it. You can also use a third party SharePoint migration tool such as Vyapin's [Dockit Migrator for SharePoint](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools) which supports granular form migration.